# Page break does not work in subreport (rdlc)

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

I have main report and subreport.

In subreport i added a group which breaking strings (=Int((RowNumber(Nothing)-1)/10)). If i trying to show subreport outside parent report that will be work good, but if i trying to show inside parent report, that won't be work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.